# In abelian category, a pullback whose below line is epic is a pushout. Why?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I don't know why the following statement is true:

**Theorem :** In an abelian category, if the following diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X' @>{f'}>> Y' \\
@V{g'}VV  @VV{g}V\\
X @>>{f}>  Y
\end{CD}
is a pullback and $f$ is an epimorphism, then the diagram is a pushout.

*My attempt :*

Assume that we are given the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X' @>{f'}>> Y' \\
@V{g'}VV  @VV{b}V\\
X @>>{a}>  Z
\end{CD}
Since the following diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{ker}(f) @>{0}>> Y' \\
@V{i_f}VV  @VV{g}V\\
X @>>{f}>  Y
\end{CD}
is commutative, we have a morphism $k:\mathrm{ker}(f)\to X'$ such that $g'k=i_f$ and $f'k=0$.

Then, $ai_f=ag'k=bf'k=0b=0$. And since $f$ is epi, $(Y,f)$ is a cokernel of $i_f$. Then we can make $h:Y\to Z$ such that $hf=a$. But, how can i show that $hg=b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commutative diagram like yours induces a complex
$$X'\stackrel{\iota}\to X\oplus Y'\stackrel{\pi}\to Y$$
where $\iota$ is $(g',f')$ and $\pi$ is $(-f,g)$. The commutative square is
 a pullback iff
$\iota=\ker\pi$ and a pushout iff $\pi=\text{coker}\,\iota$.

As you have a pullback,
$$0\to X'\stackrel{\iota}\to X\oplus Y'\stackrel{\pi}\to Y$$
is an exact sequence. If $f$ is epi, so is $\pi$ and so we have a short
exact sequence
$$0\to X'\stackrel{\iota}\to X\oplus Y'\stackrel{\pi}\to Y\to0.$$
Then $\pi=\text{coker}\,\iota$: the commutative square is a pushout.

Comment: I checked all detail. I totally understood your answer. Thank you.