# Pullback of epi is epi in abelian category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I want to understand why, in the pullback [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FVuQ.png), the map $A \times_C B \to B$ is an epi. I assume $f$ is an epi. I am hoping for a proof from the axioms of an abelian category, so please don't use an embedding theorem unless you also prove it.

Here is my attempt. We want to show $h: A \times_C B \to B$ is epi, so let $d: B \to D$ be an arbitrary epi such that $d \circ h = 0$. Creating the pushout of $(d,g)$ gives us [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TroHu.png) diagram. I use the result I read about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649656/in-abelian-category-a-pullback-whose-below-line-is-epic-is-a-pushout-why) (which I would love to see a complete proof of) to say that our original square is a pushout. Then, in the diagram [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Grg.png) the dotted map is unique. I kept trying stuff after this, but I now think I was reasoning in error, so I'll leave it here.

Comment: To be clear, I have seen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2793459/why-are-epis-stable-under-pullback-in-an-abelian-category this question and answer. I was not satisfied, so if possible please provide a more complete proof.

Comment: I think this is proved nicely in Mac Lane's chapter on abelian categories, specifically in his section on diagram lemmas.